# How to resolve key/value pair with external .config file

Tags: winforms, app-config, key-value-store, grasshopper, .net-4.7.1

I am specifying `<appSettings>` in my app.config file, I am adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="ShareAppSettings.debug.config"/>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

ShareAppSettigns.debug.config is my external config file, which I am using on my local machine and I do not want to share it with the rest of my team.

ShareAppSettings.debug.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="clientID" value="11" />
  <add key="clientSecret" value="11" />
  <add key="tenantID" value="11" />
</appSettings>
```

Whenever I am trying to debug the main code:

```
private static List<string> AppCredentials()
{
   string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"];
   string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];
   string tenantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantID"];

   List<string> appCred = new List<string> { clientID, clientSecret, tenantID };

   if (clientID == null)
       throw new Exception("ShareAppSettings.Debug.Config file was not provided in this repo.");

   return (appCred);
}
```

For some reason I am not getting values for clientId, slientSecret nor tenantId. This code is a part of grasshopper Add-on for v6 template, and its running on .NET Framework 4.7.1. Whenever I copy the same code into a new C# console of a same framework, the code is built. I would truly appreciate if you could give me suggestions on how to solve this.

What "EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" means and how can make this work?

Many Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIxj8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the **`file`** attribute (corresponding to the [AppSettingsSection.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.appsettingssection.file) property) instead of the **`configSource`** attribute (corresponding to the [SectionInformation.ConfigSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource) property) in the **`appSettings`** section.

- `configSource` doesn't support other keys in the section, while `appSettings` may contain other keys, needed by the Application and possibly somewhere else (someone else may add/remove them - for testing purposes or any other reason).

The `file` attribute allows instead the presence of other key in the `appSettings` section.

Your `app.config` file can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="ShareAppSettings.debug.config">
        <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2"/>
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Now the values are accessible by both opening a named configuration section:

- `appSettings.Settings[]` returns a [KeyValueConfigurationElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.keyvalueconfigurationelement)

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");

var kvpClientID = appSettings.Settings["clientID"];
var kvpClientSecret = appSettings.Settings["clientSecret"];
var kvpCenantID = appSettings.Settings["tenantID"];

string clientID = kvpClientID.Value;
```

and directly, using [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings) - a [NameValueCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection) - which returns the value of the specified key:

```
string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"];
string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];
string tenantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantID"];
```

As a note, using the `file` attribute, your `ShareAppSettings.debug.config` doesn't need (but it's not forbidden) the XML header, it can be just:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="clientID" value="11" />
  <add key="clientSecret" value="11" />
  <add key="tenantID" value="11" />
</appSettings>
```

Secondary note:
you can set the `file` attribute to point to another file at run-time and refresh the `appSettings` values to updated the configuration.
Note that, if a `file` attribute was already set, all values contained in that `.config` file are not *dismissed*, but instead moved to the `[Application].exe.config` file, to become part of the `<appSettings>` section (thus, they are preserved).
Another reason why using the `file` attribute may be preferable.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var appSettings = config.AppSettings;
appSettings.File = "SomeOtherFile.config";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```